# What is a shortcut for hints in kdevelop?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kdevelop

For example I have a function f:

```
int f(int a) {
  return a;
}
```

or something. Then whenever I call it, I want to see what arguments it takes, in Eclipse I can do `ctrl + space`, what about kdevelop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the `Customizing code auto-completion` web page:

> On the other hand, **Full completion** will additionally show the type for
>   each entry, and in the case of functions, also the arguments they
>   take. *Also, if you are currently filling in the arguments to a
>   function, full completion will have an additional info-box above the
>   cursor that will show you the current argument you are working on.*

I think you need to switch to the `Always full completion`:

> The editor's code completion can be customized via Settings →
>   Configure Editor → Editing → Auto Completion.

Read more about customization in [here](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/extragear-kdevelop/kdevelop/customizing-code-auto-completion.html).

Comment: There's no "always full completion" option there, or what do you mean? By the way, my system, for some reason, set ctrl+space to switch between languages I use on my system, I think that could interfere with the ctrl+space hints.

Comment: Yes that might be the reason too. You can try changing language switch shortcut to something else, then see if it works. To enable full completion Go to Settings -> Language Support, then change the value of the "Detailed Completion" dropdown menu.

Comment: Yea, it was, I just installed kubuntu and everything works.